# wp_insert_post() inside save_post(): force WP to not update global post object?

Tags: plugins

I wrote a custom plugin which inserts another metabox on the edit post screens. Once the user saves or publishes an article, I want to create another post with a custom post_type, which works great. However, data from other metaboxes are saved with the post_id of my newly created custom-typed-post instead of the original post. I suspect this is due to wp_insert_post() updating the global $post object with the post_id the function just generated.

But how can I make sure this does not happen? How to make sure, e.g. all other plugins also using the save_post hook save their data correctly to the right post instead of my custom-type-post created by wp_insert_post()?

```
add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'save_post'), 1, 1);

public function save_post($post_id) {

            // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
            // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
            if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
                return;
            }


            if($_POST['post_type'] == self::POST_TYPE && current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
            {

                $newContestAdded = false;

                $_STBKT_assignedContestHopper = get_post_meta($post_id, '_STBKT_assignedContestHopper', true);
                if (($_STBKT_assignedContestHopper=='' || $_POST['STBKT_quickcontest_contestID']=='') 
                        && get_post_type($post_id) == 'post') { 
                    // Create contesthopper post object
                    $CH_post = array(
                      'post_title'    => '',
                      'post_content'  => '',
                      'post_status'   => 'publish',
                      'post_author'   => 1,
                      'post_type'     => 'contesthopper'
                    );

                    $_STBKT_assignedContestHopper = wp_insert_post( $CH_post, $wp_error );
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I think how it works is that wp_insert_post ends up calling wp_update_post which then fires the save_post action which generally results in a loop. you can do some hacky stuff using globals or temporally remove the action.  the latter method is even mentioned in the wp docs for save_post i believe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to thoroughly test this (and your code is not of the complete class anyway), so understand that there is a lot of guessing to this answer, but `save_post` will run again when you call `wp_insert_post`. I think it may be that second run that is causing the problem. If so, you should be able to avoid the issue by having your callback remove itself from the `save _post` hook.

```
add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_post'), 1, 1);

public function save_post($post_id) {
    remove_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_post'), 1, 1);
```